# C++ Preprocessor: Iterate over comma-separated list argument

Tags: c++, c-preprocessor

I'm trying to generate comma-separated list of vectors of given types to instantiate std::variant of vectors. (I didn't want to write a huge one-line code so I decided to use macros. I am open to new suggestions for this root problem).

Is it possible to write macro which would define a preprocessor variable which would appear to be a list of comma-separated vectors of given types:

```
#define INTEGRAL_TYPES char, int, long long, size_t
#define MAGIC_MACRO(x) ???

#define SEQUENTIAL_TYPES MAGIC_MACRO(INTEGRAL_TYPES) // this will generate std::vector<char>, std::vector<int>, std::vector<long long>, std::vector<size_t>
```

Comment: Why? Can't you separate this out before putting it in as code? This is a one-time thing or a routine operation?

Comment: Tip: This is what `constexpr` can help with. Don't think the preprocessor is the only answer.

Comment: Hi @tadman, list of types generated by `MAGIC_MACRO(x)` is used by various parts of code. To avoid code duplication I decided to use general approach. Also types may be changed during development.

Comment: Can you show how this might be used? It's not clear how much "magic" that macro has. Types in templates can do a lot of heavy lifting if you structure it right.

Comment: @asynts, thought it might make me look polite. I do vote up every answer that is useful.

Comment: @tadman, as I noted in the question I need to declare variable of type std::variant. It should look like this:
`std::variant<SEQUENTIAL_TYPES> var;`

Comment: @asynts Has an answer below that's right on the money.

Comment: The "useful" part is important, don't just up-vote all answers. The only "obligation" you have, is to try to find a solution yourself before asking and trying to minimize the problem as much as possible. (From what I can tell, you did that.)

Comment: You *could* do this with variadic macro arguments, but you really shouldn't in c++. See asynts answer for a better solution.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This can be done with C++ templates:

```cpp
#include <variant>
#include <vector>

template<typename... Types>
using VariantVectorGenerator = std::variant<std::vector<Types>...>;

using MyWeirdVariantVectorThing = VariantVectorGenerator<int, double, float>;

int main() {
    MyWeirdVariantVectorThing x;
    x = std::vector{42};
    x = std::vector{13.2};
}
```

In this case `int, double, float` could be moved into a macro. Not sure to which extend it is possible to simplify this.